# Javascript Testing with Mocha.js: How to mock out a callback in mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

My test:

```
describe("Something", function() {
  it("does the right thing", function(done) {
    callExternalApi(["mockData1", "mockData2"], function(err, ajaxResults) {
       // how do I mock out the api requests here and return mocked err, and ajaxResults
    });
  });
});
```

My function:

```
function callExternalApi(data, callback) {
   $.ajax({
      ...blah..
      success: function(ajaxResults) {
        callback(null, ajaxResults);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        callback(err, null);
      } 
   })
}
```

Ideally, I don't want to have to do some sort of http mock. I just want this function to not be called and return something to be in the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). I've been able to use it to great effect in my node.js apps. You can use it to stub out jQuery's `ajax` method and make the stub call your callback function with something like this:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax");
stub.yieldsTo("success", [{ foo: "bar" }]);
```

Don't forget to restore the stub with `stub.restore()` when you're done.

Take a look at [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/docs) for more advanced usage.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout https://github.com/pgte/nock It provides a simple and clean way to simulate responses to http requests by intercepting the directly!

for example if your app calls www.api.somesite.com/items/item7 you can simply define it previous to your test like this:

```
var nock = require('nock');
var item7 = require('./item7.json');

var scope = nock("www.api.somesite.com").get("/items/item7").reply(200, item7);

//Your test here.
```

Also checkout its recording feature!

Comment: Nock cannot handle browser ajax call... Only node and limited http lib